# User interaction outside the UIView bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, screen

What i'm trying to do is "navigating" into a bigger UIView with buttons and controls positioned in different places. I've made the size of the main UIView twice bigger than the usual. It is 640x480 instead of 320x480.

After clicking a button in the first part of the screen i've made a moving translation of -320px in the x-direction to show the second "hidden" part of the screen where other functions will reveals to the user. Everything works perfect apart the fact i can't get the UIView back to the original position. It seems that the button i use to get back to the original position and that is "outside the bounds" of the 320px, doesn't work.

My UIView is referenced as "introScreen", and the following is the function i call to translate the screen through the x direction:

```
- (void)secondPartOfTheScreen {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.15];
        introScreen.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Calling this function my UIView moves correctly, but when my button appear in this part of the screen, it doesn't get any user interaction. If i move that button in the first part of the screen, it works correctly. It have something to do with the screen bounds? It is possibile to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the transform property properly, you should take into account the previous value of the property like this:

```
introScreen.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(introScreen.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0));
```

Hope this helps, and check [Apple's UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) and [CGAffineTransform documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much irodrigo17! The translation works correctly with your code, but i can't get the button to work in the part that reveals when the translation animation ends, in order to get back to the original position. That button, outside the 320px bound, doesn't get any user interaction. Any idea? :)

Comment: Hey, take a look at [this sample project](https://github.com/irodrigo17/sample-code/tree/master/StoryboardsTest) I uploaded for you at my GitHub account, it does exactly what you want I think. And I didn't need to subclass UIView.

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted! Thank you irodrigo17!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to give something back to this amazing community!

Answer (score 6):

You should try to subclass your `UIView` and override its `pointInside:withEvent:` method so that also a point outside its bounds is recognized as belonging to the view. Otherwise, there is no chance that user interaction outside of the view bounds are handled as you would like to.

This is what the [Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) say:

> In hit-testing, a window calls hitTest:withEvent: on the top-most view of the view hierarchy; this method proceeds by recursively calling pointInside:withEvent: on each view in the view hierarchy that returns YES, proceeding down the hierarchy until it finds the subview within whose bounds the touch took place. That view becomes the hit-test view.

You could use something like this in your custom `UIView`:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
      if (view.userInteractionEnabled && [view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event]) {
        return YES;
      }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

You could do with this:

```
@interface MyView: UIView
@end

@implementation MyView

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
      if (view.userInteractionEnabled && [view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event]) {
        return YES;
      }
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

add this class definition to the beginning of the `.m` file where you are using the view. (You could also use separate .h/.m files, but for the sake of testing if everything works, it is enough). Then, replace `UIView` with `MyView` in the instantiation of your current `UIView`, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much sergio! You was really helpful! I will get more information on subclassing UIViews!

Comment: It's really easy, you do not need to do anything special: just declare your class as derived from `UIView` and then define the method I suggested above in the implementation part. Ah, don´t forget to instantiate it where you need to use it!

Comment: Well i'm new to xcode programming so some things aren't very clear yet. I'm getting better but some parts needs more attention. :) When you say "declear the class as derived from UIView", you mean something like this?

- (UIView *)introScreen:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGFloat radius = 100.0;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(-radius, -radius,
                              self.frame.size.width + radius,
                              self.frame.size.height + radius);
    
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point)) {
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

Comment: Actually Sergio both the solutions, the yours and the one of irodrigo17 works great... i'm going to test both, to better understand the mechanism behind it. :)

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

First why would you use transform when you are merely moving the object. You can set the frame just as easily.

```
CGRect frame = introScreen.frame;
frame.origin.x -= 320;
introScreen.frame = frame;
```

(Yes this will work inside an animation)

second, if you translate a view its contents should be within its bounds regardless of the size you want displayed in the first place.

therefore your container view (the one with the buttons) should be a size so that all contained pieces are within its bounds. Anything outside its bounds will not function. Having the main view twice its size is not as useful as having the contained view at twice its size.

Think of it like this.

Your table should be able to hold whatever your looking at. If you have a map you want to display you would slide it around on the table. the table does not need to be as big as the map but the map needs to be big enough to present you with all of its contents. if the map was say too short to display the poles and you would be without the information. No matter how much you transformed the map you would not be able to use the north or south poles..

To ensure the app reflects this you can turn on clip subviews on all the views in question, then if its outside the bounds it will not be visible.

Comment: Thank you Volure. I understand what you mean. Well, all the buttons and graphics elements are all parents of the UIView i want to move. I'm using the transform function just for aesthetics reasons, to slide nicely between the controls. The first part of the UIView slides correcly, but the controls that are in the this part of the screen, doesn't work. I think that Sergio got it right: i can have user interaction only within the standard bounds of 320. I should subclass my UIView, to override "pointInside:withEvent:", unless there is another way to do it :)

Comment: well. if you clip subviews you will not see any items outside the bounds of your view. Also. if you move the frame within the animation code, (i believe you are just moving it to the left) than it will act the same and animation should handle frame movement just as smoothly. Almost all of my animation code is movement of frame rather than transform